# TypeError: "_vm.KisanData is undefined" in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I cannot fix the error please help.

this the method where use KisanData but error occur i cannot fix this problem

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/User";
    export default {
      name: "home",
      info(){
        return{
        info: [],
        KisanData: {
          name: "",
          village: ""
        },
        }
      },
```

here this is the html code where i use v-model but error occor

```html
<span class="input10" for="name">Name</span>
                  <input
                    id="name"
                    class="input1"
                    type="text"
                    v-model="KisanData.name"
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Enter your name" required
                  />
                  <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input100" data-validate="Name is required">
                  <span class="input10" for="village">Village</span>
                  <input
                    class="input1"
                    id="village"
                    type="text"
                    v-model="KisanData.village"
                    name="village"
                    placeholder="Enter your Village name" required
                  />
```

```
error occur on console
```

Comment: please don't notice parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use field `data` intead of `info`:

```js
const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/User";
export default {

    name: "home",

       data() {
            return {
                info: [],
                KisanData: {
                   name: "",
                   village: ""
                },
            }
        }
},
```

Comment: i change but new error occur "property or method “name1” is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Comment: Man i dont see any property or method "name1" in your code. Can you mark my answer as a correct answer to give me some point? i helped you with your currect problem.